# Error when using staticmethod with flyweight decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, flyweight-pattern

I have a class for making sprites flyweight and I am using a decorator to call this class. Here is some code:

```
class flyweight:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._cls = cls
        self.__instances = dict()

    def __call__(self, title):
        return self.__instances.setdefault((title), self._cls(title))
```

In this question I'll just simplify the code to show what is relevant.

```
@flyweight
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, title, surf=None):
        self.title = title
        self.surf = surf if surf is not None else pygame.image.load('Images/Sprites/'+title+'.png').convert_alpha()
        self.w, self.h = self.surf.get_size()

    @staticmethod
    def from_colour(colour, size=(40,40)):
        surf = pygame.Surface(size).convert(); surf.fill(colour)
        return Sprite(colour, surf)

red = Sprite.from_colour((125,0,0))
```

But this gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'flyweight' object has no attribute 'from_colour'
```

Should I remodel my flyweight implementation or is there some way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `flyweight` decorator really ought to pass through all constructors to the underlying class, including `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` alternate constructors. In fact, more generally, a class decorator really ought to preserve the wrapped class's entire public interface.

And, while we could easily modify `flyweight` to specifically pass through the rest of the `Sprite` interface, which in this case is just that `from_colour` method, that would be a pain for a less trivial class, or for a class that ever changes. And really, what's the point of making a decorator that only works with a single class?

So, let's change it to:

- Take any constructor signature. Ideally we'd want to make it configurable on what part of the signature counts as the key,<sup>1</sup> but to keep things from getting too complicated, let's just fix it as the first argument.
- Pass through the entire public interface of the class, not just its `__call__` interface.

So:

```
class flyweight:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._cls = cls
        self.__instances = dict()

    def __call__(self, key, *args, **kw):
        return self.__instances.setdefault(key, self._cls(key, *args, **kw))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not name.startswith('_'):
            return getattr(self._cls, name)
```

---

<sub>1. Some other library I've used has a nice design for this for function memo caches. Probably `cachetools`. And it ought to make just as much sense for class construction caches.</sub>

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once decorated, the name of the wrapped object automatically points to the returned results of the decorator. In this case, `Sprite` now stores an instance of `flyweight`, which in turns contains an attribute storing an instance of the original wrapped class `Sprite`. For instance, printing `Sprite` after the declarations gives: `<__main__.flyweight object at 0x102373080>`. However, the `staticmethod` `from_colour` can be called from `_cls`:

```
red = Sprite._cls.from_colour((125,0,0))
```

Comment: While this works,I don't think it's a great answer. Obviously `from_colour` was supposed to be part of the public interface of `Sprite`. But instead, you now have to call it via a private attribute. Worse, a private attribute of a class that users of `Sprite` shouldn't have to know about. Especially since you ought to be able to drop `@flyweight` in and take it back out without changing anything but performance, and you definitely can't if it obscures the interface of the decorated class.